# Choose parameter converter in jax-rs

Tags: java, jax-rs

Say I have:

```
class Person {
  int id;
  String name;
}
```

and a resource:

```
class CountryCodeResource {
  @GET public String getCountryCodeByPersonId(@QueryParam("id") Person person) { ... }
  @GET public String getCountryCodeByPersonName(@QueryParam("name") Person person) { ... }
}
```

I can make a `ParamConverter` for each of the cases:

```
class PersonByIdParamConverter implements ParamConverter<Person> {
  @Override public Person fromString(String value) {
    int personId = Integer.toString(value);
    return lookUpPersonById(personId);
  }

  @Override public String toString(Person person) { ... }
}

class PersonByNameParamConverter implements ParamConverter<Person> {
  @Override public Person fromString(String value) {
    return lookUpPersonByName(value);
  }

  @Override public String toString(Person person) { ... }
}
```

How do I specify which one to use? I.e. is there something similar to this in jax-rs:

```
class CountryCodeResource {
  @GET public String getCountryCodeByPersonId(@QueryParam("id")
    @ParamConverter(PersonByIdParamConverter.class) Person person) { ... }

  @GET public String getCountryCodeByPersonName(@QueryParam("name")
    @ParamConverter(PersonByNameParamConverter.class) Person person) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Create a `ParamConverterProvider` and implement the `getConverter(Class<T>, Type, Annotation[])` method. The `Annotation` array will allow you to read the annotations from the method parameter. Then you can decide which converter you'll use.

Comment: [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48115377/1426227) may give you some insights.